# CSS @import statement

Tags: css, grails, less

I'm currently using the Initializr generated Bootstrap enhanced version of the HTML5 Boilerplate which also includes the LESS framework.

Now the style.less is being included by the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="${resource(dir: 'less', file: 'style.less') }">
```

This works, but the line `@import('bootstrap/bootstrap.less')` fails, because it cannot find the `bootstrap.less` file in `/static/less/bootstrap/bootstrap.less`. However, the file is available without the `static` part.

Is there something I need to tell Grails to put the not directly in a GSP page referenced files (what kind they may be of) in the right directory, i.e. `static`?

I found an issue regarding this problem: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-135 - this is telling me, that it has been fixed in version 1.2, I am currently using 2.0.2.

What do I have to do, to make this work?

Comment: Note that the version 1.2 that you referred to is the version of the _plugin_.  The latest plug-in version is 1.1.6 so the fix hasn't been implemented yet, at least not in a released version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed the `lesscss-resources` plugin which precompiles `LESS` files. This way, I can also use the `@import` statements.

I have defined my core stylesheets as a module in `ApplicationConfig.groovy`.

```
modules = {

    // ...

    sitecore {      
        dependsOn 'jquery'

        resource url:'less/style.less', attrs:[rel: "stylesheet/less", type:'css'], bundle:'bundle_sitecore'
        resource url:'js/main.js'
    }
```

And by doing so, I can just reference it using the Resources plugin of Grails:

```
<r:require module="sitecore" />
```

Comment: Have you found a way to get the plugin to process changes to the imported file? Currently I'm having to restart grails to get them picked up.

Comment: Didn't do much more with Grails for a long time, I'm afraid I can't help you on this one.