# Grails - LESS CSS @import issue

Tags: grails, plugins, import, less, grails-plugin

I am unable to import a .less file into another one. I get a "file not found" exception, although I triple checked the path and syntax were right.

Here is how I try to import the file from within my `importingFileName.less`:

```
@import 'main';
```

Here is how I set the resources in my ApplicationResources.groovy

```
modules = {
    application {
        resource url: 'js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js', disposition: 'head'
        resource url: 'js/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js', disposition: 'head'
        resource url: 'js/libs/jquery.form.js', disposition: 'head'
        resource url: 'js/application.js', disposition: 'head'
    }

    css {
        resource url: 'css/mobile.css'
        resource url: [dir: 'less', file: 'importingFileName.less'], attrs:[rel: 'stylesheet/less', type:'css']
    }
}
```

Here is how I call the resource from the GSPs:

```
<r:require modules="application, css"/>
```

Here is what I get:

```
ERROR resourceMappers.LesscssResourceMapper  - error compiling less file:
/home/userPath/.grails/2.0.3/projects/myApp/tomcat/work/Tomcat/localhost/_/grails-
resources/less/importingFileName.less

Message: Couldn't load main.less
```

If I bundle everything into the `importingFileName.less` file, the CSS is loaded correctly using those settings. 
Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Have you added `importingFileName.less` to your ApplicationResources (like it shows here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548564/css-import-statement)?

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes may cause problems depending on what version of the plugin you are using. See https://github.com/paulfairless/grails-lesscss-resources/issues/26.

Try  this:

`@import "main.less";`